# Run ruby code on link_to (external link)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to update my db with some information when the user clicks on one of the links (All directed outside my website) in a dynamically built table.

I'm running the code to update the db via an ajax request.

HTML:

```
<%= link_to('Link text', service.link, class: 'service_link') %>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.service_link').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 
            beforeSend: function() {
                <% Lead.create (...) %>
            }
        })
    });
```

2 Questions:
1. Is there a simpler way than ajax to run the 2 lines of ruby to update the db.
2. Since my link list is built dynamically I'm looking for a way to transfer which link was clicked as a parameter to the ajax request.

any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: It's hard to see what you're trying to do, but using `$(this)` inside the `beforeSend` function will give you exactly what was clicked. Using this information, you can explore the DOM to get the information you are looking for.

Comment: The main problem I have is that I need to find a way to combine ruby code with javascript code and do something like this (I know it's not working, It's just to explain the concept: "<% @active_link = %> $(this).attr('id')"